# I want to if I select Year Radio button, select opeion value 2018 selected, now no one selected

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular5

I want to if I select Year Radio button, select opeion value 2018 selected, now no one selected.

class code are :

```
alls:string='';
type:string ='1';
yData = [{"Year":2018},{"Year":2017},{"Year":2016}]`enter code here`
```

This is Template code:

```
<div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" value="1">All Search</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" value="2">Album Title </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" value="3">Year </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" value="4">Event Date </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="type" name="type" value="5">Description </label>
            </div>

    </div>


<div *ngIf="type === '1'">All Search:<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="alls" /><br></div>
<div *ngIf="type === '2'">Album Title: {{this.type}} <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="alls" /></div>
<div *ngIf="type === '3'">Year: {{this.type}} alls {{yData[0]["Year"]}}
<select [(ngModel)]="alls">
<option *ngFor="let yrow of yData" [value]="yrow.Year"> {{yrow.Year}} </option>
</select>
</div>
<div *ngIf="type === '4'">Event Date: {{this.type}} <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="alls" /></div>
<div *ngIf="type === '5'">Description:  {{this.type}}  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="alls" /></div>
```

As above in angular 5 code.

Comment: if you select 2018 option? then what you expecting to happen ?

Comment: Well, your select's ngModel (which holds the selected value) is `alls`. Its value is `''`. Why would that select 2018?

Comment: Sir, There are two block, one for radio button and another for display input controls, which is related from radio button, like if 'type' value is equal 3 then year select controls will display, which is working perfect, but in select controls data are coming from yData,(is comming from http.get().subscribe()), But I need in select option default value should be 2018(first index). I hope you understand what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You must say Angular what happends if you change the "type". So, you must "separate" ngModel and ngModelChange. If you use simple [(ngModel)] you only can change the variable "type"

```
<input type="radio" value="3" [ngModel]="type" 
           (ngModelChange)="type = 3;alls=yData[0].Year">
```

Other way to achieve the same is using a getter setter and use [(ngModel)]

In your .ts

```
_type:number;
get type(){
   return _type;
}
set type(value:any)
{
   this._type=value;
   if (this._type==3)
      this.alls=this.yData[0].Year
}
```

Other way is using Reactive Form and change, see https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms

Comment: No sir, I need set the default value in drop-down option of select. Data are coming but fist is blank. whine i click in select then I can set any value. But I need selected property as working on simple html...